# Spring jpa - can't use more than one EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, entitymanager

I'm working on a java spring mvc application that uses hibernate and jpa for persistence layer. I have 2 databases and I want map some entity tables in database1 and some in database2. So I have defined two configuration classes like this:

**First:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module.common",entityManagerFactoryRef = "commonEntityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef = "commonTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceConfigCommon {

    public PersistenceConfigCommon() {
    }


    Properties additionalProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {  
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
            }
        };
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "commonEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory commonEntityManagerFactory() {entityManagerFactoryBean");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("common");
        factory.setDataSource(commonDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "commonDataSource")
    public DataSource commonDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.11:3306/database1?characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        dataSource.setUsername("fpuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("fpdb$123456");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "commonTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager commonTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
           transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(commonEntityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

**Second:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module.profile",entityManagerFactoryRef = "profileEntityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef = "profileTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceConfigProfile {

    public PersistenceConfigProfile() {
    }


    Properties additionalProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {  
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
            }
        };
     }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "profileEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory profileEntityManagerFactory() {entityManagerFactoryBean");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("profile");
        factory.setDataSource(profileDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "profileDataSource")
    public DataSource profileDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.63:3306/database2?characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        dataSource.setUsername("fpuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("fpdb$123456");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "profileTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager commonTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
           transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(commonEntityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Note everything is similar in these two files, just `common` has been converted to `profile` in the second file and database name and ip has been changed. Also in the DAOs I have put this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "common") //or "profile"
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}
```

Now, when I run the project, I get the following exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: commonEntityManagerFactory,profileEntityManagerFactory
```

I have bee stuck in this exception for 2 days. Could anyone help me to solve this problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you, but try to change the return value of `commonEntityManagerFactory()` and `profileEntityManagerFactory()` from `EntityManagerFactory` to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and return those factory instances instead of `factory.getObject()`. This is something I have in my current project and it works fine.

Another guess: which Spring Framework version do you use? The thing is that recently there was a regression in Spring Framework related to your issue. Take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2409) and [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12541) for example. The regression was in 4.1.4. If you are sure that your configuration is ok, try experimenting with a different Spring version. Hope this helps

Comment: I tested your suggestion, but still same exception :(

Comment: @hamed I updated my answer with another guess, hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using spring 4.0.1.. Maybe upgrading to 4.1.1 solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, you should try it out. Also it would be good if you edit your question and add a bit more info about your configuration (e.g. how your repository is annotated, from where you try to access `EntityManager`, relevant persistence.xml if any, application context xmls if any) Maybe missing parts of information could help the community to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `"common"` as a unitName and you have two `@Primary` annotations.
Try configuring:
`@Bean(name = "common")` instead `@Bean(name = "commonEntityManagerFactory")`

Comment: Persistence unit name is specified explicitly via `factory.setPersistenceUnitName("profile")`

Comment: My bad ;). But still you have defined two EntityManagerFactories as default candidates for autowiring. As I racall this may be confusing for spring. as per documentation of @Primary: `Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value.`

Answer (score 0):

Since it is Spring-Jpa configuration, you propably need to make in that way:

**First:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module.common",entityManagerFactoryRef = "commonEntityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef = "commonTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceConfigCommon {

    public PersistenceConfigCommon() {
    }

Properties additionalProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {  
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
            setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
        }
    };
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "commonEntityManagerFactory")
@Qualifier(value="commonEntityManager")
public EntityManagerFactory commonEntityManagerFactory() {entityManagerFactoryBean");
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(commonDataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module");

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}


@Primary
@Bean(name = "commonDataSource")
public DataSource commonDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.11:3306/database1?characterEncoding=UTF-8");
    dataSource.setUsername("fpuser");
    dataSource.setPassword("fpdb$123456");

    return dataSource;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "commonTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager commonTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(commonEntityManagerFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
}
```

**Second:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module.profile",entityManagerFactoryRef = "profileEntityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef = "profileTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceConfigProfile {

    public PersistenceConfigProfile() {
    }


    Properties additionalProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {  
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
            }
        };
     }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "profileEntityManagerFactory")
    @Qualifier(value="profileEntityManager")
    public EntityManagerFactory profileEntityManagerFactory() {entityManagerFactoryBean");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(profileDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.project.persistence.orm.module");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "profileDataSource")
    public DataSource profileDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.63:3306/database2?characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        dataSource.setUsername("fpuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("fpdb$123456");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "profileTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager commonTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
           transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(commonEntityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

**Example of injection:**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="profileEntityManager")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}
```

Comment: I tested, but still same problem.

Comment: Did you try to remove `@Primary` annotations from your code and see results ?